# how you check the constructor values in java class?

Tags: java

I have a MyDate class, within this class, I need to check if the year (y) is leap year. My code is as follows:

```
public class MyDate
{
    private int d;
    private int m;
    private int y;

//constructor

public MyDate(int d, int m, int y)
    {
    this.d = d;
    this.m = m;
    this.y = y;
    }

    public void setDay(int d)
    {
        this.d = d;
    }

    public int getDay()
    {
        return d;
    }

    public void setMonth(int m)
    {
        this.m = m;
    }

    public int getMonth()
    {
        return m;
    }

    public void setYear(int y)
    {
        this.y = y;
    }   

    public int getYear()
    {
        return y;
    }



    public void setDate(int d, int m, int y)
    {
        setDay(d);
        setMonth(m);
        setYear(y);
    }
```

here instead of (int y), do I need to use getYear()?

```
public static boolean isLeap(int y) {
  if (y % 4 != 0) {
    return false;
  } else if (y % 400 == 0) {
    return true;
  } else if (y % 100 == 0) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

//like this?

```
public static boolean isLeap(getYear()) {
  if (y % 4 != 0) {
    return false;
  } else if (y % 400 == 0) {
    return true;
  } else if (y % 100 == 0) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: `int y` is the parameter of the `isLeap` method. Probably you want to use `getYear()` when calling the `isLeap` method.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza post it as an answer

Comment: @MrD I'm not sure if that will answer OP's question. If you feel it would, you can use my comment as part of your answer.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoaz, I am really new to java. I have to do bunch of functions in this class to check the values of d, m, y. in publi static bolean, should I just put (int y), or (getYear())? I am not really how does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is static, so you should use the following if the method must be `static`

```
public static boolean isLeap(int y)
```

because you can not call getYear() in a static method.It does not belong to an object, it belongs to a class.
If it is possible to change the method as non-static

use

```
public boolean isLeap(){
int y = this.getYear();
....
...
}
```

Comment: Note that `isLeap` method is marked as `static`. Probably OP must not want to change this.

Answer (score 0):

The second version does not pass compilation:

`public static boolean isLeap(getYear()) {`

Take a look on this. First, you cannot call method inside declaration of other method. Second, you cannot call instance method from static method.

You can change the method signature as following:

```
public boolean isLeap() {
    // here you can access either instance field y or method getYear()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't write your own class for this.  `java.util.GregorianCalendar` does everything your class can do, and it has a method called `isLeapYear()`.